# Create a new column by match conditional in two columns in pairwise dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, pairwise

I am trying to create a new column by conditionals in the matching of two columns with the same factors, in order to summarise the data.

This is how looks the dataframe

[image]

This is how I want to summarise

[image]

This is my proposed not working code:

```
probe$Cluster<-"cluster"
for (i in 1:length(probe)){
if(is.na(probe[i,4])){
probe[i,9]<-probe[i,6]}
if(is.na(probe[i,6])){
probe[i,9]<-probe[i,4]}
if(identical(probe[i,4],probe[i,6])){
probe[i,9]<-probe[i,4]}}
if(!identical(probe[i,4],probe[i,6])){
probe[i,9]<-probe[i,4]
rep(probe[i,1:9]%>%probe[i,9]<-probe[i,6}
#Then create a summary of this like this:
Sum<-probe%>%group_by(Method,Cluster)%>% summarise(mean(relation, na.rm 
=FALSE),numberobservations=length(unique(GenA)))%>%data.frame()
```

Thank you for any advise

Comment: Please provide data that we can use. The gold-standard is posting the output from `dput(probe)` into a code block in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't verify without sample data that I can load (without retyping from a picture), but it looks like you're going for something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
probe %>%   
  mutate(Cluster = coalesce(ClusterA, ClusterB) %>%   # use 1st non-NA from cols
  group_by(Method, Cluster) %>%   
  summarize(mean = mean(relation, na.rm = TRUE),
            numberobservations = n(), .groups = "drop")
```